# How to ssh into Google Cloud Shell?

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-shell

I'm having a weird error: the web shell for a Google Cloud shell is spewing endlessly my typing.  [youtube clip of error](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OyYsVOcdICw)

'gcloud auth login' worked as expected.

I want to skip using the web shell and use regular ssh on mac osx into the cloud shell instance.

Using hostname nor the values mentioned below works.

In web shell:

> darian_hickman@darianhickmancom:~$ hostname
>   cs-6724-devshell-vm-9f3fde16-797e-4327-99a7-5c2710f10920-289
>   darian_hickman@darianhickmancom:~$ domainname (none)

On my local terminal:

> DarianMac:~ darianhickman$ gcloud compute ssh
>   darian_hickman@darianhickmancom ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) Could not
>   fetch instance:
>    - The resource 'projects/darianhickmancom/zones/us-east1-d/instances/darianhickmancom'
>   was not found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of early 2018, it is now possible to connect Google Cloud Shell from terminal.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58528852/291180) to [Is it possible to use the Google Cloud Shell via a ssh?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41324702/4271787)
 for details.

Answer (score 1):

SSHing directly into a Cloud Shell instance is not supported. If you must use your own SSH client, I recommend looking into Google Compute Engine instances.